# Interaction between ViewComponent and his Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

For example, I have ViewComponent BookShelf, which main idea is to add books to shelf. Components files:

*(~/Views/Shared/Components/BookShelf/Default.cshtml)*

```
<form id="addForm" asp-controller="?" asp-action="?" role="form" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" name="bookName" value="exampleValue"/ >
    <button type="submit"> Add book </button>
</form>
```

*(~/ViewComponents/BookShelfViewComponent.cs)*

```
public class BookShelfViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public RoleManagementViewComponent(
        ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
         _dbContext = context;
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IViewComponentResult AddBook(string bookName)
    {
         //Some database logic to add book
    }
}
```

So, the main question is how to pass book name to AddBook method in this ViewComponent? What should be in *asp-controller* and *asp-action* attributes? And maybe i shouldn't return IViewComponentResult, if I want to reload ViewComponent after adding book?

Comment: Is BookShelfViewComponent your controller?

Comment: @Anonymous this is default controller for _BookShelf/Default.cshtml_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you still need an for an answer on this, but I might as well mention that ViewComponents don't handle HTTP requests. ViewComponents help deal with the rendering side of things. You'll want to use a Controller to handle POSTs such as "adding a book".

Here is a really raw example of a POST involving both the view and a controller:

View

```
<form asp-controller="Items" asp-action="Create">
    <input type="text" name="item" value="exampleValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

ItemsController (naming convention important)

```
    // POST: Items/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(string item)
    {
        //do you string db thing
    }
```

Comment: So, I should use ViewComponents only for static rendering, like lists? And for requests  we still need full controller, which just handle data requests and that's all?

Comment: If you like, ViewComponents could still pull data from the database to render in the view. Yes, you will need a controller to handle HTTP requests. Just remember that in ASP.NET MVC, responding to requests is their job. You could have other layers in your app actually perform the data access, but it's because the controller will be asking them to.

Comment: There's a challenge handling problems if the ViewComponent does too much, such as hitting APIs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858676/how-to-return-http-status-codes-for-errors-from-asp-net-core-view-component/52099814#52099814

Comment: @Casey Can you please kindly check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777025/how-to-download-the-coverted-doc-file-from-viewcomponent