# How to return HTTP Status Codes for errors from Asp.Net Core View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am trying to return a HTTP 500 or BadRequest() result from my View Component in Asp.Net Core however this return type does not appear to be available for View Components. Should status code return types be available for View Components or have i got my design wrong?

I am calling my controller action via ajax as per below...

```
<a asp-controller="Client" asp-action="LoadVisit" asp-route-id="@item.VisitID" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-update="#ClientVisit" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-failure="AjaxOnFailure(xhr, status, error)" role="button"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i></a>
```

My controller action is calling/returning my View Component as per below...

```
public IActionResult LoadVisit(int? id)
{

    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return ViewComponent("ClientVisit", new { visitID = id.GetValueOrDefault() });

}
```

My ClientVisit View Component has the following...

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int? clientID, int? visitID)
{

    try
    {
        var model = new VisitViewModel();
        model = await visitAPI.GetVisit(clientID, visitID);
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

When my database call `model = await visitAPI.GetVisit(clientID, visitID)` fails I want to return `return StatusCode(500, ex.ToString())` but it's not available so my ajax call thinks my request was successful which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have the HttpResponse in the access it should work. Alternatively, due to the return of the ViewComponent prerequisite check then set the status.

```
try
{
    var model = new VisitViewModel();
    model = await visitAPI.GetVisit(clientID, visitID);
    return View(model);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately HttpResponse is not available in View Component. Compile error _The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context_

Comment: How is it when you check the result from  ´ViewComponent("ClientVisit", new { visitID = id.GetValueOrDefault() });´ like:

`var view = ViewComponent("ClientVisit", new { visitID = id.GetValueOrDefault() });
if(view == null)
{
     Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
     return null;      
}

return view;`

Comment: You could find `Response` in `HttpContext` for example: `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = ???;`, but still it will not work, becouse "a view component never directly handles a request".

Answer (score 2):

From [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) documentation:

> A view component never handles a request,
>
> view component methods are overloaded on the signature rather than any details from the current HTTP request,

So as far I understand you will not be able to create HTTP response (like as `StatusCode()` or `BadRequest()`) inside your View Component.

You could access `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode`, but this also will not work as you want.

You cannot return `null` from View Components - you will see the exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: A view component must return a non-null value.
```

Due to above, I have no idea how to return status code from View Component.

Perhaps, you can convert View Component into simple 'helper' method, so you could catch an exception in action and then return `StatusCode(500)` as you want?

Answer (score 2):

The containing controller should own the logic deciding whether to return status codes and then only if there isn't a problem should it pass the required data to the view component. This should eliminate any need for the view component to interact with the pipeline.

> View components don't use model binding, and **only depend on the data provided when calling into it**.

So move the call to the api **out** of the view component and into the controller and then pass the resultant data into the view component if the call to the api was okay.

ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1

So something like this for your example:

```
public IActionResult LoadVisit(int? id)
{

    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var model = new VisitViewModel();
    try
    {
        model = await visitAPI.GetVisit(clientID, visitID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.Message);
    }

    return ViewComponent("ClientVisit", model });

}
```

and

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(VisitViewModel model)
{
        return View(model);
}
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using a view component in this scenario? If all of the work is done in the controller then why not just return a partial view instead which is easier to setup than a view component? I thought the purpose of view components was that it could process logic to avoid plumbing through a controller.

Comment: View components can be shared as a dll / nuget package. Partials can't without resorting to pre-compiled views. There may be other reasons but that's the one of interest to us at the moment.